# Foreach returns only one row

Tags: php, foreach

I have foreach loop, but it only returns a single option in select menu. Vardump shows multiple results. What am I missing?

```
$vars = explode(';', $this->settings['address']);

foreach ($vars as $row) {
    return array(
        'title' => $this->name,
        'options' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 'option_1',
                'icon' => $this->settings['icon'],
                'name' => 'Option 1',
                'description' =>'',
                'fields' => '<select name="address" class="form-control">' . PHP_EOL
                . '<option value="'.$row.'" >'.$row.'</option>' . PHP_EOL
                . '</select>' ,
                'cost' => $this->settings['fee'],
                'tax_class_id' => $this->settings['tax_class_id'],
                'exclude_cheapest' => false,
            ),
        ),
    });
}
```

Comment: You're returning inside of your foreach. Build up an array, then return it after the loop.

Comment: return ends the function immediately. replace it with `$output[] = array(...` and then `return $output;` at the end

Comment: you are returning the array with only one option in the first foreach iteration. You should add it to an array and return it after the foreach.

Comment: Can you add some sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$vars = explode(';', $this->settings['address']);

$options = [];
foreach ($vars as $row) {
    $options[] = array(
        'id' => 'option_1',
        'icon' => $this->settings['icon'],
        'name' => 'Option 1',
        'description' =>'',
        'fields' => '<select name="address" class="form-control">' . PHP_EOL
            . '<option value="'.$row.'" >'.$row.'</option>' . PHP_EOL
            . '</select>' ,
        'cost' => $this->settings['fee'],
        'tax_class_id' => $this->settings['tax_class_id'],
        'exclude_cheapest' => false,
    );
}

return array(
    'title' => $this->name,
    'options' => $options
);
```

Or maybe this

```
$options = '';

foreach ($vars as $row) {
    $options .= '<option value="' . $row . '" >' . $row . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
}

$fileds = '<select name="address" class="form-control">' . PHP_EOL . $options . '</select>';

return array(
    'title' => $this->name,
    'options' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 'option_1',
            'icon' => $this->settings['icon'],
            'name' => 'Option 1',
            'description' =>'',
            'fields' => $fileds,
            'cost' => $this->settings['fee'],
            'tax_class_id' => $this->settings['tax_class_id'],
            'exclude_cheapest' => false,
        ),
    ),
});
```

Comment: This only returns the last value of the array.

Comment: Result for var_dump ($row): string(4) "1111" string(6) " 2222" string(6) " 3333" string(6) " 4444". And options dropdown only shows 4444 with your code, mine was only showing 1111, so it's either first or last.

Comment: try my second solution

Comment: are you try it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185543/discussion-between-joedoe-and-davit).

Answer (score 1):

```
$vars = explode(';', $this->settings['address']);
$myReturn = array();
foreach ($vars as $row) {
    array_push($myReturn, array(
        'title' => $this->name,
        'options' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 'option_1',
                'icon' => $this->settings['icon'],
                'name' => 'Option 1',
                'description' =>'',
                'fields' => '<select name="address" class="form-control">' . PHP_EOL
                . '<option value="'.$row.'" >'.$row.'</option>' . PHP_EOL
                . '</select>' ,
                'cost' => $this->settings['fee'],
                'tax_class_id' => $this->settings['tax_class_id'],
                'exclude_cheapest' => false,
            ),
        ),
    ));
}
return $myReturn;
```

Comment: This completely hides my select option menu.